# How to group common initializations in constructors?

Tags: java, android, constructor

I'm writing an Android application in Java. My class has two constructors - one is used when data is being passed directly and the second if class should deserialize the data from bundle. Everything looks more like the following:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final ObservableInt myField;
    private final int data;

    public MyClass(int data) {

        myField = new ObservableInt();
        myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);

        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyClass(Bundle bundle) {

        myField = new ObservableInt();
        myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);

        this.data = bundle.getInt("SomeName");
    }
}
```

Consider the above a simple example. I have a lot more final fields to fill and also a lot more `data`-type fields.

Now note, that this code is repeated in each constructor:

```
        myField = new ObservableInt();
        myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);
```

I'd like to refactor it to single place to avoid DRY problems. I tried to create private constructor and call `this()` in each of the constructors above, but the compiler complains, that "data" field might not have been initialized and I don't want to pass it via parameter to that private constructor, because in my case there are a lot of `data`'s to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use initializers like that:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final ObservableInt myField  = new ObservableInt();
    private final int data;
    {
       myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);
    }

    public MyClass(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyClass(Bundle bundle) {
        this(bundle.getInt("SomeName"));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what he already has and what he doesn't want anymore to not repeat the `this.data = ` twice (if i understood his question)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley No, not really. I don't want to repeat `myField = new ObservableInt()` and `myField.addOnChangeListener(myListener);`. I guess it actually may solve my problem.

Comment: @Spook oooh so I probably have to go back to sleep! sorry for my misunderstanding!

Comment: Good response. You can simplify calling `this(bundle.getInt("SomeName"));` in `MyClass(Bundle bundle)` constructor.

Answer (score -1):

> tried to create private constructor and call this()

You might not be always possible to go for DRY, but in your case I'd chain the constructors:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final ObservableInt myField;
    private final int data;

    public MyClass(int data) {
        myField = new ObservableInt();
        myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);

        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyClass(Bundle bundle) {
        this(bundle.getInt("SomeName"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the "int" constructor as default:

```
public class MyClass {

  private final ObservableInt myField;
  private final int data;

  public MyClass(int data) {
    myField = new ObservableInt();
    myField.addOnChangedListener(myListener);
    this.data = data;
  }

  public MyClass(Bundle bundle) {
    this(bundle.getInt("SomeName"));
  }
}
```

Comment: So now you removed your silly comment you posted under my answer but left your downvote? That's really childish behavior.

Comment: downvote? I deleted the comment because I understood that you edit your answer just after posting mine and that they are exactly the same could be coincidence given the briefness of the question.